# Neighborhood of $a$ when $f'(a)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f$ that I know is continuous and differentiable everywhere.

I was reading the following theorem:

"Suppose the function $f$ is defined on a neighborhood of $x=a$ with $f'(a)>0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(a) < f(x_1)$ for some $x_1 \in (a, a+\delta)$ and such that $f(x_2) < f(a)$ for some $x_2 \in (a - \delta, a).$"

I also have a theorem that states "If the function $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'(x) = 0$ on $(a,b)$, then $f$ must be the constant function."

If I know that at some $x=a$, $f'(a) = 0$, what can I say about $f$ around a sufficiently small neighborhood of $a$? Can I claim that $f(x_2)=f(a)=f(x_1)$ on $(a - \delta, a +\delta)$ by using the first theorem? Meaning does the theorem apply when $f'(x) = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Look at $f(x) = x^2$, $f'(x) = 2x$

Clearly $f'(0) = 0$,  but there is no $x_1 \neq 0$ such that $f(x_1) = x_1^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(a)=0$, we can't claim anything about the value of $f$ in a neibourhood of $a$.

$f$ could have a minimum at $x=a$. E.g. $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=0$. $f'(x)=2x$ and $f'(0)=0$. For all $x\in(0-\delta, 0+\delta)$, $x\neq 0$ $f(x)>f(0)$.

$f$ could have a maximum at $x=a$. E.g. $f(x)=-x^2$ at $x=0$. $f'(x)=-2x$ and $f'(0)=0$. For all $x\in(0-\delta, 0+\delta)$, $x\neq 0$ $f(x)<f(0)$.

$f$ could have an inflexion point at $x=a$. E.g. $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$. $f'(x)=3x^2$ and $f'(0)=0$. For all $x\in(0-\delta, 0)$, $f(x)<f(0)$ and for all $x\in(0, 0+\delta)$, $f(x)>f(0)$.